# create on screen menu for all android versions

Tags: android, android-menu

I know that for the last few versions of android, the on screen menu button is been obsolete, and the phone's menu button is used instead. Is there a way to have the on screen menu no matter what version of android is been used on the phone?

I have seen apps using the on screen menu, even on my phone where i do have the hardware menu button. Even Google's Gmail have that feature. I would like it if i could do what the Gmail menu does, that is sliding from the side when you drag your finger over it, but that's a secondary question right now.

I believe it is a good idea having the screen menu no matter the OS version, having a brand new phone with a brand new OS, doesn't mean that you know how to use it, does it?!

Anyway, my question is, can i force an on screen menu button for newer versions of the OS?
Thanks

Edit:

Question revised, how can i add an action bar with an action overflow for all android versions, instead of the Menu item that i have now as such

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.quecustomer.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>       
     <item
        android:id="@+id/see_ticket"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/see_tickets_Menu"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>         
</menu>
```

Comment: Please try to come up with proper technical names for UI components you have in mind, rather than "the on screen menu button". Any menu button is technically displayed on a screen so it is impossible to know what exactly you are talking about.

Comment: The on-screen menu was found on a android help article, so i thought that this was the right name for it. Overflow seems to be the right name for it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are confused. The "on screen" menu button is called the overflow button. Google has deprecated use of hardware menu buttons. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html